# Firefox 120: panel not shown when I click the extensions button

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Running Firefox 120.0.1 64-bit on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, with user.js [Betterfox/yokoffing](https://github.com/yokoffing/BetterFox)

Upon clicking the "Extensions" puzzle button, instead of the regular panel showing up, the "about:addons" tab opens. This is preventing me from using several of my extensions. Although I am aware there is a solution at the [Firefox help page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-button#w_why-is-the-panel-not-shown-when-i-click-the-extensions-button)

*If no extensions are installed or if all extensions are either disabled or pinned to the toolbar, the extensions panel is not shown. Instead, the Add-ons Manager Personalize Your Firefox page will open in a new tab.*

I have checked both of these, and they are not the case. The extensions are neither disabled nor unpinned. Any help?

Comment: I have Windows and Firefox with a few active Extensions, and clicking the puzzle icon opens About:AddOns as well. However, even going into the menu and clicking Add ons and Themes loads this same page. It appears to me this is the new standard extension UI in Firefox, for better or worse.

Comment: That's disappointing, as Firefox is one of the best browsers out there. This could be a deal-breaker for me.

Comment: Sorry, I find that odd, but I suppose there's little accounting for taste. Is there something specific you are trying to solve, something the addons page doesn't do for you? What are you trying to accomplish that requires the "regular panel"?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not normal behaviour. I just upgraded to Firefox 120 and I'm seeing the same, on Linux. In the about:extensions page, the extensions appear activated, however, they are not. I think this is a bug.

Update: I managed to "fix" this by disabling and then re-enabling each individual extension. After that, the extension button gives you a list of extensions in a pull-down dialog, as it did before the update.